# Why can't I print in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I try to print in Google Chrome it says "Loading Preview" and just hangs there.  Up to this week it has been printing fine.  What can a technophobe like me do?

Comment: Delete your Chrome profile.

Comment: Years later... I had this problem, and deleting the profile helped (none of the other things you can find on the net did). Only problem is that you need to configure your chromium again afterwards - not so complicated in case you sync your browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome [updated](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2012/07/stable-channel-release.html) last week.  There are numerous reports of such behavior.  From the [Google Chrome forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/windows/4tf4W9eSGFE) dated Aug 3rd...

> The team has identified the issue and is working on a fix.  In the
>   meantime, you can try these solutions:
>
> 1. Installing either the XPS Essentials Pack, NET 3.0 or NET 3.5 should resolve the issue (note: make sure to restart Chrome after
>      installing)
> 2. Use "Save as PDF" or Google Cloud Print printers
> 3. Use the local system dialogue-- either by clicking the system link in print preview or using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
>      <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is getting this, what helped me was quite simple.

I've setup Google cloud printing today, and had the "Loading preview" issue as well.

It turns out that a simple restart to both chromes (on the printer-connected computer, and the  client computer).

Make sure you really restart chrome and not just the visible window (you can make sure by restarting the computer).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the printer again. When I tried to print I saw that my printer was selected. Then nothing happened. When I looked for other printers it found my printer again, this time with "AirPrint" at the end. Apparently the same printer looks like two printers to the computer, one connected by cable and one connected by wifi.
[image]